# "None" em vez de [1,1,1,1]

Tags: python

Eu estou fazendo um problema que funciona assim: Por exemplo, suponha que um time de 4 vendedores de telemarketing deve fazer 6 ligações, cujos tempos sejam 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9. Como inicialmente nenhum vendedor está ocupado, o primeiro vendedor fará a ligação de 5 minutos, o segundo vendedor a ligação de 2 minutos e os vendedores de número 3 e 4 farão ligações de 3 minutos. Como o segundo vendedor terminará a sua ligação antes dos demais, ele fará a quinta ligação, de 4 minutos e, por fim, o terceiro vendedor (cujo tempo é igual ao do quarto vendedor, mas o seu número de identificação é menor) fará a sexta ligação, de 9 minutos.

A função tem que retornar uma lista com o número de ligações que cada vendedor fez. No exemplo acima, teria que retornar [1,2,2,1].

Meu código está por enquanto só avaliando se o número de vendedores é igual ao número de ligações ou maior. Porém, estou printando um exemplo em que esse número é igual, e ele está retornando "None" em vez de [1,1,1,1].

```
def ligacoes(n,l):
"Retorna uma lista que contem quantas ligacoes cada vendedor fara, seguindo as regras"
resultado = []
#v = numero de identificacao dos vendedores
    if n == len(l):
        for n in range(len(l)):
            resultado = resultado + [1]
    if n > len(l):
        for n in range(len(l)):
            resultado = resultado + [1]
        resultado = resultado + [0]

print ligacoes(4,[3,3,4,5])
```

Comment: arrume a identação do código - como está não é possível saber o que está dentro da funão ou não.

Comment: desculpe, eu nem reparei  que não tava identado. foi na hora de colar aqui no site. já arrumei.

Comment: @W.Lucas falta `return resultado`

Comment: caraca verdade, esqueci do return. que erro de iniciante jesus kkkk muito obrigado!! não deu o resultado que eu queria mas pelo menos não deu none (acho que agora eu sei arrumar)

Comment: votando para fechar por conta de se tratar de um erro trivial (esqucimento do return) já entendido pelo A.P.